# How do I setup Visual Studio Code to correct my code, based on the linting rules from my .eslintrc.js in the project root?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslintrc

Visual Studio Code IDE doesn't seem to find the error in the typescript code (a missing private/public):

`draggedFromListTask: TaskConfig;`

Running `eslint ./src/classes/sequence-handler.ts` from the project root gives the right error:

> 25:5   error    Missing accessibility modifier on class property
>   draggedFromListTask  @typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility

The `.eslintrc.js` is in the root.

How do I know that the `eslint` command is using this `.eslintrc.js` file? And how do I make the `VS Code` to use this file to check my code?

From the VS Code settings.json file:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
"eslint.options": {
    "configFile": "C:\\ws\\intellilift\\RoboticDriller\\robotic_driller_frontend\\.eslintrc.js"
}
```

`

Comment: Do you have [vscode-eslint extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint) installed?

Comment: franke567, yes I do.

Comment: In VS Code at the bottom right of the window, you should see an ESLint label with two ticks. Click on that and it should show you the Output tab in the terminal window with the drop down set to ESLint. In this output, it should show you where the ESLint library is being loaded from (or if there are any errors detecting it).